# Text message archive?

Tags: iphone, text

Occasionally my ex and i will have texting conversations.  I would like to be able to save these digitally for my records.  Is there a way to save these conversations as a text file?  Right now I only know how to send myself an email with a singular text.  Not useful for a 50 text back and forth conversation about our kids.  I have an iphone 6

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a Mac?

Comment: What device (e.g. iPhone) do you each use for texting.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to use it for and if you have a Mac or PC, there are multiple solutions:

On a Mac: for example use http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/, can also Google for alternatives

On a PC: the PC counterpart is http://www.copytrans.net/download.php

Since you mention your ex and your son, you might need these for legal purposes (hope not for you!).
In this case screenshots might be your best bet, as your lawyer might want to see those if things get rough (still your iPhone will be the best resource, so don't delete them there):
Scroll to the top of the messages you need

1. If timestamps are of value, swipe in from right side of screen to
   show them
2. Press the `power button` (top right of iPhone) and the `Home` button
   at the same time for ~1.5 secs and release
3. Scroll down so the last sentence which you just screenshotted is
   shown at the top (thus the order of messages can easily be deducted)
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 as often as needed

Good luck!